# TTS with Arabic voice

Tags: android

I need to make my TTS android app able to read text in Arabic. Could some one tell me how can  I do it?I just know that I have to use  SVOX Arabic TTS, but I do not know what I  should after this.I am using eclipse.

Comment: I've never used SVOX, but I've gotten Google's TTS to work with Chinese. Try this and see if works `http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ar&ie=utf-8&q=` and fill in your text after `&q=`. You can then grab it using a standard HTTPUrlConnection.

Comment: could you share your code